# Karaf shell command

Tags: java, shell, apache-karaf, karaf

The [Karaf 4 documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/) mentions the [ability to script](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_scripting_2):

> It’s possible to create objects to create commands "on the fly":
>
> ```
> karaf@root()> addcommand system (($.context bundle) loadClass java.lang.System)
> ```

However this does not work, and displays the following error message:

> Command not found: addcommand

How to fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command 'addcommand' dose not exists!

This works:

system=(($.context bundle) loadClass java.lang.System)

$system currentTimeMillis